# Como usar soquetes para enviar um arquivo .txt para o servidor e no servidor receber esse arquivo e salvar no diretório?

Tags: c#, socket, cliente-servidor

Estou a três dias tentando entender como isso funciona e procurando exemplos, acontece que a maioria ensina como enviar mensagens de texto ou chats entre o servidor e o cliente, além disso não estou usando o windows forms e todos os exemplos que encontrei era com o windows forms...

Consigo estabelecer a conexão entre o cliente e o servidor mas não consigo transferir o arquivo de texto ou o servidor não consegue receber... acontece que o programa não lança nenhuma exceção, como se tivesse acontecido tudo como esperado, mas ele não cria o arquivo .txt.

Esse é o meu cliente que envia o arquivo .txt:

```
public void Client()
    {
        try
        {
            ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(dns);
            ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 2500);

            // Create a TCP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);    
            try
            {
                string fileName = caminho + "wrt.txt";

                Console.WriteLine("Sending {0} to the host.", fileName);

                //O código abaixo são informações necessárias para salvar o arquivo recebido
                byte[] nomeArquivoByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
                byte[] tamanhoDoNomeDoArquivo = BitConverter.GetBytes(nomeArquivoByte.Length);
                byte[] dadosDoArquivo = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                byte[] clientDados = new byte[4 + nomeArquivoByte.Length + dadosDoArquivo.Length];

                tamanhoDoNomeDoArquivo.CopyTo(clientDados, 0);
                nomeArquivoByte.CopyTo(clientDados, 4);
                dadosDoArquivo.CopyTo(clientDados, 4 + nomeArquivoByte.Length);

                client.Connect(ipEndPoint);
                client.Send(clientDados);

                // Release the socket.
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Enviado com sucesso.");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

E este o servidor, quem recebe o arquivo e salva no meu diretório:

```
        private void Servidor()
    {
        try
        {
            ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipEnd);
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(ip, int.Parse(porta));
            tcpListener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Server iniciado");

            Socket client = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

            client.ReceiveBufferSize = 16384; //tamanho do buffer 16kb

            Console.WriteLine("Recebendo arquivo");

            byte[] dados = new byte[1024*5000]; //tamanho máximo de 50mb para armazenar o arquivo
            int tamanhoBytesRecebidos = client.Receive(dados); //verificando tamanho do arquivo
            int tamanhoNomeArquivo = BitConverter.ToInt32(dados, 0); //tamanho do nome do arquivo
            string nomeArquivo = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dados, 4, tamanhoNomeArquivo);

            BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(caminhoRecepcaoArquivos + nomeArquivo, FileMode.Create));
            bWriter.Write(dados, 4 + tamanhoNomeArquivo, tamanhoBytesRecebidos - 4 - tamanhoNomeArquivo);//grava o arquivo recebido

            bWriter.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Recebido com sucesso!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Acontece que o código segue normalmente sem lançar nenhuma exceção, então eu fico sem saber o porque eu não consigo receber o arquivou, ou então, por que eu recebo e ele não salva no diretório? Se alguém puder me ajudar, ou tiver uma outra forma de implementar isso, seria de grande ajuda.

@Edit: Falei com um amigo e resolvi o problema com essa linha:

```
byte[] nomeArquivoByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```

Eu estava passando não só o arquivo como a pasta completa, por isso não conseguia passar o arquivo.

Créditos ao @DarkSkeleton

Comment: de uma olha nos exemplos de [socket send](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.sendfile?view=net-5.0) e [socker receive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Receive_System_Byte___)

Comment: Já tinha visto os dois links, vasculhei a net inteira e não achei nada que me ajudasse a enviar um simples arquivo de texto...